# PDF creation on Android

Tags: java, android, database, pdf, visualization

im working on an Application for Android that lets you put data in a database. (Standard Database Gui). But now comes the trickier part. I have to convert this Data into a PDF and send it per E-Mail or to a printer.

I'd have loved to use PDFBOX from Apache but it seams that it is dependent on AWT.
I know this question has been has asked before, but that was quite some time ago, maybe someone wrote a translation (Like JavaMail) or someone is working on a fake AWT lib for Android, that would solve such Problem.

Or even better, someone knows a better lib or a better format with lib (It should be readable be multiplattform PCs, established and free, and i'd like to avoid HTML, because my Boss told me that hed prefer something else).

So, anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not say what you tried so far I will throw you a few links in the subject. Did you check out [droidtext](https://code.google.com/p/droidtext/)? There is a [tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/05/tutorial-22-generate-pdf-using-droidtext-in-android/) on how to use it as well.

Maybe this could be something to look into?

Comment: Sry, i haven't tried to much so far. I tried to get PDFBOX to run with android regardless and took a look on iText, but its Liscencing was too complicated. Then i googled for some other libs, but i couldn't find something. But thanks for droidtext, i'll hae a look at it

Comment: actually droidtext seams alright, thx you helped me a lot.